# How can I change the color of a tapered hr?

Tags: html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMfBv/

```
hr {
border: 0;
border-color:blue;
background-color:blue;
color:blue;
height: 4px;
background:#fff;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,hsla(0,0%,0%,0)), color-stop(50%,hsla(0,0%,0%,.75)), color-stop(100%,hsla(0,0%,0%,0)));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 10%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
background:    -moz-linear-gradient(left,  hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 10%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
background:     -ms-linear-gradient(left,  hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 10%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
background:      -o-linear-gradient(left,  hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 10%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
background:         linear-gradient(left,  hsla(0,0%,0%,.75) 10%, hsla(0,0%,0%,0) 100%);
}
```

I wish to change the hr's color to blue.Clearly, the color, background-color setting is not working, how can I do this?

Comment: you mean you want it to transition from what it is currently to black on white, or you just want it to be different?

Comment: just want it to different, that is now the hr is black in color, I want it to have say blue color.

Comment: I've edited the question likewise, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: You just want it to be blue? Like this you mean:http://jsfiddle.net/Pevara/ZMfBv/2/ ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMfBv/3/ that way? You can use [this](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) for creating css gardients.

Comment: `background-color: blue` is not working because you're overwriting it with `background`.

Comment: @Le_Morri:I have a black background on my app, so how can I edit this to get a white-grey fade(left to right)?

Comment: @Le_Morri Figured it out from your link, great link, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMfBv/3

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(3,0,221,0.75) 10%, rgba(255,255,255,1) 100%);
```

Use blue as the color, rather than black. You can use this for creating css gradients.

Answer (score 2):

update: Here is a black background with a white to gray gradient hr

```
body {background-color: black;}


hr {
    height: 4px;
    border: 0;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #f3ffff, #555555);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,#f3ffff,  #555555);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left, #f3ffff,  #555555);
    background: linear-gradient(left, #f3ffff,  #555555);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you want a solid blue color, right ?
I so then here is the simplest solution.

```
hr {
    border: 0;
    border-color:red;
    color:red;
    height: 4px;
    background: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ZMfBv/13/

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this is not what I asked, one of the comments answered the question.